# String not changing to uppercase

Tags: python-3.x, list, uppercase

I would like to know why am I not getting the desired output ?
my code -

```
 = ['', '']
for i in :
  print(i.upper())
print()
```

OUTPUT -

```
['', '']
```

Desired OUTPUT -

```
FREE
CODECAMP
['', '']
```

Comment: This works as expected.  I get the desired output in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: @Amy Did you _copy_ the text or _retype_ it?

Comment: as @DYZ mentioned below, my strings were written in mathematical monospace font that's why I wasn't getting the desired output

Comment: Ah, since the code was so short, I simply re-typed it.   :)

Comment: For those attempting to close the post: the case, IMHO, is so bizarre that it is worth being on the books. Prove me wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your words are written in the mathematical monospace font for which there are no upper-case letters:

```
hex(ord(mylist[0][0]))
#'0x1d68f'
hex(ord('f'))
#'0x66' - this is the "normal f"
mylist[0][0] == 'f'
# False
```

So, technically everything works: `i.upper()` converts `i` to the upper case, but since there are no upper-case letters, the result of the conversion is the same string.

Comment: can you help me understand your code ? how did you deduce that it is 'mathematical monospace font' ?